# how we can get all document that have period time more than some min

Tags: mongodb

Let assume we have 3 documents. The first one is created 6:00, the second one at 6:25 and the third one at 7:00. How can I write a query to get all documents after 5:45 that the period of time between them is less than 30 min? In current example i want get first and second because the third one is more than 30 min from the last one.

Comment: It is unlikely that you get an answer to such a question. Check how to ask a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I posted an answer, please tell if it is useful (or any questions about it).

Answer (score 0):

Save period in number format.

`collection.find({ period : { $gt :  5:45, $lt : 30}})`

Comment: thanks for your reply but this give me the range from a time to a time but what I need is to get a series of the document base on the time, until time  for last 2 document is more than 30 min

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = db.times.find( { time: { $gte: ISODate("2019-12-30T04:00:00.000+00:00") } } ).sort( { time: 1 } ).toArray();

const THIRTY_MINS = 30 * 60 * 1000;
var prevTime = arr[0].time;
var set = new Set();

for ( let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++ ) {

    if ( ( arr[i].time - prevTime ) <= THIRTY_MINS ) {
        set.add( arr[i - 1] );
        set.add( arr[i] );
    }

    prevTime = arr[i].time;
}

var resultArr = [...set];
```

Verify with input documents:

```
{ time: ISODate("2019-12-30T06:00:00.000+00:00") },
{ time: ISODate("2019-12-30T06:25:00.000+00:00") },
{ time: ISODate("2019-12-30T07:00:00.000+00:00") }
```